# Dot product between position vector and wavenumber vector

Tags: fourier-transform

In [this paper](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/j100210a011), at some point the author is making a Fourier transform. This Fourier transform generates two spaces, one from which we may extract a position vector $\textbf{r}$ with cartesian coordinates $x$, $y$ and $z$ as its elements, and a reciprocal space from which we may extract a wavenumber vector $\textbf{q}$ with $q_x$, $q_y$ and $q_z$ as its elements. He then calculates the dot product $\textbf{q} \cdot \textbf{r}$ and interprets it as an angle (as he is putting it into a $\cos$ function, ie $\cos(\textbf{q} \cdot \textbf{r}$)).

Why can this dot product be interpreted as an angle? Is there any Fourier transform formula which directly connects $\textbf{q}$ and $\textbf{r}$ and involves such a dot product? I don't know which keywords to put in google to find a formula table which could then point me to a demonstration.

Comment: This is the general mechanism of the Fourier transform, where a function is represented by its frequency components $f({\bf r})=\int_{\Bbb R^n}\hat f({\bf q})e^{i\,\bf q·r}\,d{\bf q}$, which is usually named the inverse transform or reconstruction formula. The forward transform gives the coefficient or amplitude function $\hat f$. (There are inevitable factors involved in the FT, where they occur depends on the implementation/convention used.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In my case I have a squared normal vector difference which ends up being Fourier transformed as follows: $| \textbf{n}(0,0) - \textbf{n}(x, y) |^2 = (2\pi)^{-2} \int_{0}^{+\infty} 2[1-\cos(\textbf{q} \cdot \textbf{r})] | n(q)|^2 dq^2$. Does this ring a bell to you?

Comment: Note that in my above comment the normal vector is 3D even though it only depends on the x and y variables, its third component being approximated to 1 because the two others are small.

Comment: Yes, that looks related. Check out the isometries of the Fourier transforms, Plancherel and Parseval. Your equation is not exactly that, but might use something similar.